# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress returning 502 Bad Gateway using hosts file

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

After successfully deployed the application (pod looks OK, logs are ok), I created ClusterIP service, then created NGINX Ingress and added host to hosts file. When I try to access `posts.com/posts`, I get 502 bad gateway error.

`ingress-srv.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: posts.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /posts
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: posts-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 4000
```

`posts-depl.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: myUser/posts
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-clusterip-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   posts.com
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

What can be the problem and where at least I should look for?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your image? Does your application listens on 4000? 502 indicates bad response from the upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems - try these and let me know if it helps or not:

1. You are missing `pathType` in your Ingress manifest. It is mandatory to provide this otherwise Kubernetes won't understand whether it is a exact match or a prefix match. Read more over [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types). (I see that @Sahadat pointed it out rightly but somehow deleted his answer).
2. You are missing port number in your Deployment manifest, it should be like below:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: posts
      image: myuser/posts
      ports:
      - containerPort: 4000
```

---

UPDATE 1:

One more potential problem could be this entry in your host file - `127.0.0.1   posts.com`, delete it and try.

Comment: @hagrawal Thanks for your help! I've updated the answer with the proposed changes, but still, I cannot get it to work. 502 Bad Gateway if I try to access it.

Comment: @lecham Remove this entry - `127.0.0.1   posts.com` and then try.

Comment: @hagrawal In such case, I wont be able to access it locally. That's the problem, I'd like to test it on my local machine

Comment: I don't get it - are you using minikube for running Kubernetes or what? If you want to access your Service from outside your cluster then you need a NodePort or LB type of Service.

Comment: Try this command and tell me what you get - `kubectl get ingress ingress-srv`

Comment: ```k8s % kubectl get ingress ingress-srv
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS       ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-srv   <none>   posts.com   localhost   80      3h26m```

Comment: @hagrawal After I apply changes to ingress, I use `kubectl apply -f .`. I wondering why isn't it updated? And the port is 80.. So the changes aren't applied

Comment: Million dollar question - how are you running Kubernetes in your local - are you using minikube?

Comment: I think instead of `kubectl apply` you can try `kubectl update`, or for development purposes best is to delete and recreate.

Comment: Remove "    - name: posts" from your Service manifest and give output of `kubectl get service posts-clusterip-srv`

Comment: @hagrawal Using with docker on MAC, no minikube

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229606/discussion-between-lecham-and-hagrawal).

Comment: ok.. and where is your Kubernetes cluster running; how many nodes?... can you give me `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: @hagrawal ```k8s % kubectl get nodes                      
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    master   21h   v1.19.3```

Comment: Point 2 in your answer is incorrect. The ContainerPort in the deployment is purely informational. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network.

Comment: @thomas "The ContainerPort in the deployment is purely informational. " --> Could you please point to the link of official docs where I can read the same?

Comment: @hagrawal Sure thing. You can find this information in [Kubernetes API reference](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/) under `PodSec.Container`. Just `ctrl+f` for it.

Comment: @thomas: Ok. In isolation what you are saying is true, but you have to see the complete picture - he is having his Ingress and Service configured for port 4000, so he need to have his container listening on 4000. Read more over https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service (read "Note:" part)... that's why second point is correct...

Comment: With the way you phrased it, it is not correct. You are asking OP to reference ContainerPort in the deployment manifest: (You are missing port number in your Deployment manifest, it should be like below:) which makes no difference whatsoever. You can mention in the deployment manifest any port you like but this wont open anything. What you should be trying to do instead is to confirm that his container in fact listens on that port.